# Tv series and Bash-scripting

Tags: bash, subtitle

I've just downloaded a tv series season and the subtitles.

If .mp4 and .srt files have the same name vlc automatically add them to the videos.

The only thing in common they have is the number of the episode (E01, E02, ...).

I want to write a script that change automatically the names but I don't know how...

For example `AE01 Video.mp4` and `Sub E01.srt` must have the name of the .mp4
Any suggestion?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: This would probably fit better at stackoverflow.com

Comment: @palmerito0 As bash is a massive part of Ubuntu, we support questions on bash and bash scripts, it is fine here or there.

Comment: Can you provide an example video filename and its subtitle filename?

Comment: Display a directory listing in your question and detail how the files should end up.

Comment: Add your example to the question, click edit below it.

Comment: If it was written in Python, not bash, would it be OK?

Comment: Sure it's not a problem.

Comment: I thought it was easier with bash,  using Unix shell command (cp, grep, ... ) but in python it's good. I always wanted to learn it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all video files match the pattern `*Exx*.mp4` and all subtitle files match `*Exx*.srt` where `xx` is the same two-digit decimal number, you can use the following shell script to rename your files:

```
#!/bin/bash
shopt -s nullglob

printf '%s\n' *.mp4 |
sed -nre 's/^.*E([0-9]{2}).*$/\1 &/p' |
while read -r episode video; do
  for subtitle in *"E${episode}"*.srt; do
    dst="${video%.*}.${subtitle##*.}"
    if [ "$dst" != "$subtitle" ]; then
      mv -viT -- "$subtitle" "$dst"
    fi
  done
done
```

I added the interactive witch (`-i`) to the `mv` command in case there are multiple subtitle file with the same episode number in the name or a file of the same name exists already. It's also *idempotent*, meaning that running it multiple times doesn't change the outcome, so you can abort the script any time, investigate something and re-run it again later.

You can test it with some empty files created in a temporary directory:

```
mkdir /tmp/scratch
cd /tmp/scratch
touch 'AE01 Video.mp4' 'Sub E01.srt'
```

Comment: I have this error  ----- addsub.sh: line 9: syntax error near unexpected token \`then'
 ------ addsub.sh: line 9:\ `    then'

Comment: I've copied and pasted it now but i still have the error.
The backslash in the past comment was to escape " ` "